# How to connect turtlesim using android mobile in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've ROS istalled in ubuntu 10.04 and I've to control the turtlesim robot in emulator using the android mobile i.e. i've to move (right,left,up,down) the turtlesim robot using android mobile.
I've installed android_core and java_core also.

Will someone help me out in how to do this project assign to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45420/how-to-connect-turtlesim-using-android-mobile-in-ros/) by [kush6791](https://answers.ros.org/users/3349/kush6791/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-10**:
Is this for a class?

**Comment by [kush6791](https://answers.ros.org/users/3349/kush6791/) on 2012-10-10**:
No it's for the mini project to be submitted at the end of the semester.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-11**:
Then if you're really confused, go talk to your professor or TA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are always a good starting point.

Essentially, you will have to write an android node that fills and periodically publishes a `turtlesim/Velocity` message on the correct topic.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kush6791](https://answers.ros.org/users/3349/kush6791/) on 2012-10-10**:
I've studied the ros tutorials and i've also run turtlesim using the keyboard but how to connect the android mobile to give the same instruction as are given using roscore -> turtlesim turtlesim_node ->turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-10**:
You need to implement an android app that uses rosjava and publishes the same data as turtle_teleop_key. But please note that rosjava is still under heavy development and should be considered as unstable.

**Comment by [kush6791](https://answers.ros.org/users/3349/kush6791/) on 2012-10-10**:
Will you please tell me what android app i need to implement or installed in my android mobile (GT-S6102) to get the things working?
Please help me i'am not getting the things?
Please help :(